# no such file to load -- thinking-sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rubygems, thinking-sphinx, rvm

When running script commands like script/console I get the error message:

```
no such file to load -- thinking-sphinx
```

In my evironment.rb file I have:

```
config.gem 'thinking-sphinx', :version => '1.3.18', :require_as => 'thinking_sphinx'
```

In my rake file:

```
require 'thinking_sphinx/tasks'
```

I have following versions:

```
gem 1.3.7
ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.8
```

My rake commands like rake ts:rebuild work fine!
Is there a way to get rid of the annoying error message?

Tnx!!!

ps: I also use RVM

Comment: Are you sure you have `thinking-sphinx` installed? what does `gem list --local | grep thinking` return?

Comment: Thinking sphinx is installed and working fine... only when running script commands like script/console this annoying error message appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Rails is trying to require the gem as "thinking-sphinx" rather than as "thinking_sphinx". You need to use `:lib` to specify the require path rather than `:require_as` IIRC.

```
config.gem 'thinking-sphinx', :version => '1.3.18', :lib => 'thinking_sphinx'
```

Comment: Just had the same problem. Nice catch :)